# asp.netListView Insert when List is 0 items long

Tags: asp.net, listview

asp.net ListView is databound server side using a DataTable as the source:

```
Using Classes As DataTable = cMgr.getClassesDataTable(ID)
    listviewClasses.DataSource = Classes
    listviewClasses.DataBind()
End Using
```

The ListView contains an InsertItem as the FirstItem. When the ListView has 1 or more items, the inserting via the InsertItemTemplate works as expected. In some cases, the ListView has no items. In this case, inserting via the InsertItemTemplate fails due to controls located in the InsertItemTemplate showing server side as containing no data (includes TextBox, CheckBox, DropDownList, etc). These items are initializing and displaying appropriately client side, as some controls are databound server side and show that data client side. ListViews databound from an SQLDataReader instead of a DataTable do not have this same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the ListView and re-binding corrects this problem:

```
If listviewClasses.Items.Count = 0 Then
    listviewClasses.Items.Clear()
    listviewClasses.DataBind()
End If
```